# Javascript: How to check if each input value is duplicated to another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

So i have a dynamic input field came from append with different class name and names, i want to check each of input field value already exist or duplicate.

This would look like

The first criteria_name is default and the others are appendend.

```
<input type="text" name="criteria_name" class="criteria_name">
<input type="text" name="criteria_name2" class="criteria_name2">
<input type="text" name="criteria_name3" class="criteria_name3">
<input type="text" name="criteria_name4" class="criteria_name4">
<input type="text" name="criteria_name5" class="criteria_name5">
```

I am trying to check each one of those if there is no duplicated else proceed.

```
 var critname_arr = [];
 var input_check;
 var crit_name_of_first = $('input.criteriaNames').val();
 var acappended = append_crit_header+1;
 var count_to = 0;

 for(var ab = 2; ab<=acappended; ab++){
      var crit_arr;

    if(crit_name_of_first == $('input.criteria_each_name'+ab+'').val()){
        alert("Criteria cannot be duplicate");
        return false;
    }else{

        input_check = $('input.criteria_each_name'+ab);
        input_check.each(function(){
            crit_arr = $.trim($(this).val());           
        });
        critname_arr.push(crit_arr);
    }
    if($('input.criteria_each_name'+ab+'').val() == critname_arr[count_to]){
            alert('criteria cannot be duplicate');
            return false;
    }
    count_to++;
}
console.log(critname_arr);
```

Comment: You would probably help yourself to use a class as a selector instead of  an id value. Then you can just select by class and use `$.each` to iterate through

Comment: oh i forgot its class srry

Comment: still same its not comparing to each other if its duplicated,

Comment: Then this `'input#criteria_name'` won't work as a selector. You also need to use the same class name `.criteria_name`, not numbered.

Comment: ohh wait ill try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is just an example of how you can do it. In the fiddle change one of the values to one that is already in another field (make a duplicate value) to see it do something. If there are no duplicates, it will not do anything. Click the "Button" text to run the duplicate check:

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/o52gjj0u/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ter').click(function(e) {
        var stored  =   [];
        var inputs  =   $('.criteria_name');
        $.each(inputs,function(k,v){
            var getVal  =   $(v).val();
            if(stored.indexOf(getVal) != -1)
                $(v).fadeOut();
            else
                stored.push($(v).val());
        });
    });
});
</script>
<!-- Just use an array name for the input name and same class name as well -->
<div class="ter">Button</div>
<input type="text" name="criteria_name[]" class="criteria_name" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="criteria_name[]" class="criteria_name" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="criteria_name[]" class="criteria_name" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="criteria_name[]" class="criteria_name" value="4" />
<input type="text" name="criteria_name[]" class="criteria_name" value="5" />
```

Comment: interesting i try this